# How to increase friendship/compatibility between two Miis

Tags: tomodachi-life

Is there a way to get to Miis to be happier with each-other?
Oh, and I want to avoid using travel tickets, as they are ***WAY*** too hard to get. For example,
Mii A was married to Mii B.
When going to Mii A and pressing R or L (to show friendship) it says
Mii B Super Happy.
And when going to Mii B and going to the same list,
Mii A Very Happy.

Is there a way to get both Miis to be super happy or maybe at least up one?
(I.E. Mii C showed Not getting along and Mii D showed Very happy, how to get Mii C to "Kinda getting along" or "Very happy"?) or (Mii E and Mii F were *friends* this time. How to get both to show "Great pal"?)

Also,
Mii G and Mii H had a major fight.
Mii I said "Mii G and Mii H are still fighting." And you told it to help them (or accidentally chose "Not your business,") and they still fought, is there a way to restore their friendship? Or maybe after a minor fight?

Comment: Two miis just fought and didn't make up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, using travel tickets is the only tried and true way to guarantee a jump in a Mii's relationship level with another Mii (and that's only if they are already close enough friends with a certain Mii to be the one they'd choose to bring).

I've also read that making sure both Miis have the same gifts that allow them to communicate or hang out more together (i.e. both have cell phones, gaming consoles, etc.) though I don't know if there is any concrete proof backing that up.

As for the battling friends, if they are still fighting after you've tried to mediate between them I am almost positive that their friendship will come to an end organically (This happened to me only it was with a married couple and when I checked on them the day after I tried to help, it turned out that they divorced and moved out of their shared home). Since there isn't an "enemy" listing on your friends list I believe the person your Mii fought with is simply stricken from their friends list altogether, which possibly means that you may be able to befriend them again in the future.